# CountVectorizer with Pandas dataframe returning wrong shape

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, data-mining, countvectorizer

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import (f1_score,precision_score,recall_score)
ifile=open("train_pos.txt")
rows = []
for ln in ifile:
    rows.append({'text': ln, 'class': 1})
ifile.close()
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(rows)
data_frame
```

This code outputs:

```
text    class
0   Coffee is great and I live close so it's conve...   1
1   I love this place for its coffeeshop feel with...   1
2   I've come here now a couple of times and I lov...   1
3   Nice vibes, just ok food and not too warm serv...   1
4   Not a big breakfast person but this place has ...   1
... ... ...
74241   Henry the bartender makes a stop in at Bijans ...   1
74242   I love the ambiance at Bijan, especially the w...   1
74243   Popped in for Happy Hour, on a hot and stormy ...   1
74244   Update: Â Bijan's came on the scene as a great...   1
74245   The nearly day-glo lime green walls, harsh flu...   1
74246 rows × 2 columns
```

I am trying to perform feature extraction using countvectorizer with the pandas data_frame as input.

To do this I did the code

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer() 
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data_frame.text)
X_train_counts.shape
```

The problem is it is giving me the wrong shape when I run the above code. The shape is outputting (74246, 61803) but it supposed to output (74246, 2). It gives the correct output when I run
`data_frame.shape`

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you understand what `CountVectorizer` does. It converts your text into counts of tokens. You shouldn't expect only two features when you clearly have many more unique words (in this case somewhere in the range of 61,800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing fit_transform() with fit(). fit_transform() learns the vocabulary dictionary and then converts it into a document-term matrix. So you're getting a matrix not a dictionary. fit_transform is the same as running fit followed by a transform. So if you're looking for a dictionary, just use fit()